# RecyclerView in Header of another RecyclerView (Mvvm + Databinding + Kotlin)

Tags: android, mvvm, binding, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I want to  create a screen like  main screen of instagram:

[image]

Structure of this  screen  looking like (horizontal)recyclerView in  header of another RecyclerView (Vertical). But  I am not sure,  is it a best(possible) way to making it. Or what is the  best way(approach) to making this?  I would be glad if you could share with me your ideas about that.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't about asking for code and getting a full example you won't understand to drop into your code and call your own. Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry about that.  It was looking like  "I want  some codes from coders".  I edited my question.  Actually  I am asking  the best/possible and simple  way(approach) to making this.

Comment: Even as edited, this really an opinion question which isn't really a great fit for SO, but I will say that a horizontal RecylerView inside of a vertical RecyclerView will work fine, though you could consider how many items you expect to have in the horizontal one, how often they'll change, and whether you can get away with something simpler.